# Automatically forward email by VBA Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am using the code below to automatically forward email. I added an Outlook rule already.

1. Outgoing email address
   Currently: can only send 1 email
   Desire: send to many different emails
2. Email content
   Currently: no email content
   Desired: add a command about email content including ( title mail + any content )

```vb
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strMsg As String
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem

Set myFwd = Item.Forward

myFwd.Recipients.Add "xxx@xxx.com, yyy@xxx.com"
myFwd.Recipients.Add "yyy@xxx.com; zzz@xxx.com"
myFwd.Recipients.Add "zzz@xxx.com yyy@xxx.com"

xStr = "<p>" & "Hi, Your email has been received. Thank you!" & "</p>"
myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr & .HTMLBody

myFwd.Send
Set myFwd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, You can have this achieved with Outlook Rules, and is there any situation that is not working out?

Comment: I added outlook rule already.

Comment: How does your outlook rule have relevance for your code? Do you actually invoke your subrutine from the rule? you havn't explicitely said so.

Comment: @TSPham Please edit your question and include your code in. Code in comment is not formatted and hard to read.

Comment: I have run script successfully.
I've updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying where you are getting `.HTMLBody` from, but I assume it to be from the `Item` argument.

You can add that in like this:

```
myFwd.Recipients.Add "xxx@xxx.com"
myFwd.Recipients.Add "yyy@xxx.com"
myFwd.Recipients.Add "zzz@xxx.com"

xStr = "<p>Hi, Your email has been received. Thank you!</p>"
myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr & Item.HTMLBody
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much.

Now automatically sent to 3 different emails.

Can you show me how to send only 1 email to multiple Recipients.

Comment: The first 3 lines of code in my answer should demonstrate that. Each line adds one more recipient. See how they are different?

Comment: I tried 3 above ways but it doesn't work